# Run code on UI-thread but invoke callback on current thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm writing an Windows 10 Universal app. I need to run some specific code on the UI-thread, but once that code finishes, I want to run some code on the same thread that first invoked the request. See example below:

```
    private static async void RunOnUIThread(Action callback)
    {
        //<---- Currently NOT on the UI-thread

        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            //Do some UI-code that must be run on the UI thread.
            //When this code finishes: 
            //I want to invoke the callback on the thread that invoked the method RunOnUIThread
            //callback() //Run this on the thread that first called RunOnUIThread()
        });
    }
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Does it have to be the same thread, or can it be any non UI threadpool thread?

Comment: Not sure actually. The thread that's calling this code is called from Unity which runs on it's own thread (afaik) and not sure it will work. But if you give me an example I can try! :)

Comment: Also you are doing `async void`, [don't do that!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), either make your method return `async Task` or don't use a async method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just invoke the callback after the `await Dispatcher.RunAsync`:

```
private static async void RunOnUIThread(Action callback)
{
    //<---- Currently NOT on the UI-thread

    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        //Do some UI-code that must be run on the UI thread.
    });

    callback();
}
```

The callback will be invoked on a worker thread from the threadpool (not necessarily the same on which `RunOnUIThread` started, though, but you probably don't need that anyway)

If you *really* want to invoke the callback on the same thread, unfortunately it becomes a bit messy, because worker threads don't have a synchronization context (the mechanism that lets you invoke code on a specific thread). So you would have to invoke `Dispatcher.RunAsync` synchronously to make sure you remain on the same thread:

```
private static void RunOnUIThread(Action callback)
{
    //<---- Currently NOT on the UI-thread

    Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        //Do some UI-code that must be run on the UI thread.
    }).GetResults();

    callback();
}
```

NOTE: never call `GetResults` from a UI thread: it will cause your app to deadlock. From a worker thread, it can be acceptable in some cases, because there is no synchronization context, so it can't deadlock.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, why do I need GetResults()?

Comment: @user2422321, `GetResults()` will block until the operation is complete. If you don't call it, it will just continue in the background, and you will end-up invoking `callback()` before the operation on the UI thread is complete.

Comment: Ahh thank you, that would explain why it was not working the first time. However, I tried it, but I get the error: `COMException: A method was called at an unexpected time.`. Stacktrace says it coming from GetResults(). Do you have any clues?

Comment: As you've guessed it seems I didn't need GetResults(). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2422321, I didn't say you didnt need GetResults()... you do need it if you want to wait for the UI operation to complete before invoking the callback. But I forgot that you can't just call `GetResults()` on an IAsyncAction if it's not yet complete... A workaround would be to use `Task.Run(() => Dispatcher.RunAsync(...)).Wait()`, but it's a bit ugly.

Comment: Then I'm confused, your answer provides two "solutions". And you, yourself say: "but you probably don't need that anyway" - which I was referring to when I said: "as you've guessed". Why is the "Wait()" solution ugly?

Comment: @user2422321, I assumed that you didn't actually need to invoke `callback` on the same thread on which `RunOnUIThread` was called (because there are very few valid reasons to want that), but you just didn't want it to be executed on the UI thread. Is that right?

Comment: The `.Wait()` solution is ugly because it uses yet another thread just to wait for the result of `Dispatcher.RunAsync`

Comment: That is partially right. Read my comment on my original question (don't wanna extend these comments further ;) ). Anyway, thank you, I will try with both solutions and make sure at least one of them works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97283/discussion-between-user2422321-and-thomas-levesque).